# Django: count every same value in a object.filter

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a CourseEmailPersonEven model that has this:

```
class CourseEmailPersonEvent(models.Model):
uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)

action = models.CharField(max_length=32)
is_filtered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

user_agent = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
ip_address = models.ForeignKey(Ip, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
course_email_person = models.ForeignKey(
    CourseEmailPerson, related_name="events", on_delete=models.CASCADE
)
```

In a viewset (retrieve), i'm getting CourseEmailPersonEvent's informations about one single account. But I wanna add the amount of same "ip_address" used from every accounts (even mine). And I don't know what to do:

```
class UtilsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

@action(detail=False, methods=["get"], url_path="emails/events/ips")
def emails_events_ip(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    account = get_object_or_404(models.Account, uid=self.kwargs["account_pk"])

    ips_events_count = (
        models.CourseEmailPersonEvent.objects.filter(
            course_email_person__account=account,
            action="open",
            ip_address__isnull=False,
        )
        .values("ip_address")
        .annotate(Count("ip_address"))
        .order_by("-ip_address__count")
    )

    return Response(ips_events_count)
```

Here the result I wanna have in final: (to add that **"ip_address_used_all_account"** line)

```
[
{
    "ip_address": "4ead446d-28c5-4641-b44d-f1e3aa7d26f8",
    "ip_address__count": 1,
    "ip_address_used_all_account: 2,
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

How large is this table? How heavily used is this view?

The brute-force approach is that once you have established which ip object you are interested in, do a separate query to count the uses. If I've understood your model right,

```
ip_address_used_all_account = CourseEmailPersonEvent.filter( ip_address = ip 
    ).count()
```

Unless there are obvious performance issues with this approach, just keep it simple!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
class UtilsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
   @action(detail=False, methods=["get"], url_path="emails/events/ips")
   def emails_events_ip(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      account = get_object_or_404(models.Account, uid=self.kwargs["account_pk"])
      ips = models.CourseEmailPersonEvent.objects.filter(course_email_person__account=account, action="open", ip_address__isnull=False).values_list("ip_address")
      ips_events_count = models.CourseEmailPersonEvent.objects.filter(ip_address__in=ips).values('ip_address').annotate(Count('ip_address'))
      return Response(ips_events_count)
```

Comment: The first solution isn't related but about the 2nd, I have already a models.CourseEmailPersonEvent.objects.filter and what I need is, for each object of my objects.filter, I need to know to check if this IP is already used anywhere (even on others account) and add the Count of that. My problem is because i'm already filtering with one single account, I can't use your second solution because I'm filtering and I have to keep that

Comment: @Jer Ok, I have edited my answer (try something like that)